# Preview Youtube videos in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, youtube, preview

Is there a way to preview Youtube videos in Mozilla Thunderbird when you receive a Youtube link via email?

More specifically, this is what I'm after (ordered by decreasing preference):

- see the video *embedded directly in the email*, as it happens in Gmail Labs' "Youtube preview"
- see a *picture preview*, as it happens when you embed a video in a web page before clicking on it
- finally, at the very least, *show the title* of the video somewhere, e.g. on mouse hover

Are there any extensions to do that?

(Solutions for either Thunderbird 2.0 or 3.0 are ok).

Answer (score 2):

From [New in Thunderbird 3](http://support.mozillamessaging.com/bg/kb/New+in+Thunderbird+3)

> Video content can now be played in
>   Thunderbird. To play a video embedded
>   in an email, access controls from the
>   right-click context menu. (The
>   controls are not automatically enabled
>   because JavaScript is disabled in
>   emails for security reasons.) Video
>   content in RSS feeds will display the
>   controls as expected.

I haven't tried it, but you will probably need to enable JavaScript, which is somewhat of a security risk.

Also, as far as my understanding goes, this refers to embedded video, and not to simple links to video.

Comment: interesting, I'll try this out; I'm currently running version 2.0 at work but installing version 3.0 shouldn't be a problem