# oEmbed in email

Tags: email, wordpress

I'm emailing someone a draft version of a WordPress post. The post includes youtube videos and tweets. In WordPress to get the YouTube video to embeds, or the tweet to display properly you just paste the URL, no hassle.

Is it possible to get this same functionality in an email? Can I make use of the oEmbed standard this way?

I should say I'm talking directly about using the oEmbed functionality, not 'hey how to I put a youtube link into an email'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a youtube video be embedded in an HTML Email](http://superuser.com/questions/212957/can-a-youtube-video-be-embedded-in-an-html-email), also see [Preview Youtube videos in Thunderbird](http://superuser.com/questions/191956/preview-youtube-videos-in-thunderbird)

Comment: What email client are they using? What email client are you using? Can you access the email's HTML source?

Comment: I can make no guarantees about their clients. But yes I can go down in to the html at my end. :)

Answer (score 0):

Embedded content in emails is VERY unlikely to work.

The reason is that it is far too dangerous to allow given the vast volume of spam and the prevalence of serious security flaws in embedded content.

Give them access to the draft directly on WordPress or have a test WordPress instance. Either way, send them a link to the article rather than a copy.

Comment: Why would something be safe to do in a webpage but not an email?

Comment: It has a different security model. Web pages are operating in a client that shouldn't trust ANYTHING without explicit acceptance. Many email clients often operate with little attention for most of the time (in the background) and may receive 100's of times more "pages". Worse though is that they receive them from unknown and unknowable sources (since it is extremely easy to spoof sender info).